# echo not working from Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have added code to Makefile something like:

```
ifeq "$var" "1"
    var_1 := 1\
    echo "g++ version OK"\
    $(info $(var_1))
else
    echo "needs to be updated"
endif
```

I am using tabs everywhere in this part of code. It does not seem to work, nothing echoes at all when I run make, Makefile already contains the object files and flags etc. Does it have something to with the position of the code? I'm unable to identify. Please help.

Comment: please, post your entire makefile. From this snippet, the syntax you are using does not seem to be correct for `ifeq`. Also, if it is not a part of recipe then you should use `$(info "g++ version is ok")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` is a shell command, it only works from within a recipe or `$(shell ...)` function.

Anywhere else use [`$(info ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) function.

Comment: Hello. Thanks! This helps but now I have detected a new problem, variable inside ifeq does not get set, when I try to print it using $(info ..), I get nothing on console, updates in the question.

Comment: @user5400132 _I have detected a new problem_ - this calls for a new question.